# How can I get rid of the last character of a string in Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I have a bunch of strings in the format

```
x.xx%
```

or in the format

```
xx.xx%
```

with x being an integer greater than or equal to zero. I want to get rid of the percent signs so I can convert these strings to just integers. How can I get rid of the last character in a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [string functions available in Cypher](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/#query-functions-string).

You can use the [`replace()`](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/#functions-replace) string function in Cypher to search for usage of  "%" and replace with an empty string:

```
WITH replace(n.someProp, "%", "") AS value
```

Comment: Alternatively `substring(n.someProp,0, length(n.someProp) -2 )`

Comment: Is now `substring(n.someProp, 0, size(n.someProp) -1 )`